# Determine the domain of $g(x,y) = \max \big\{ \sqrt{(-1)^{[x]}}, \sqrt{-y^2+2xy-x^2} \big\}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

I have a difficulty with solution of the problem:

I am supposed to find the domain of:

$$g(x,y) = \max \Big\{ \sqrt{(-1)^{[x]}}, \sqrt{-y^2+2xy-x^2} \Big\}$$
where $[x]$ is the floor of $x$.

I know that $-y^{2}+2xy-x^{2}\geq 0$, so does the first term $\left ( -1 \right )^{\left [ x \right ]}\geq 0$.

But I do not know how to continue. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you see another way of writing $-y^2 + 2xy - x^2?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$-x^2+2xy-y^2=-(x-y)^2$$

thus

$\sqrt{-x^2+2xy-y^2}$ exists only if $x=y$.

on the other hand
$\sqrt{(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}}$ exists only if $\lfloor x\rfloor $  is even.
which is equivalent to $x\in [2k,2k+1)$.

the domain is therefore
$$\{(x,x)\in \Bbb R^2 :  x\in [2k,2k+1) , k\in \Bbb Z\}$$

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for your original question .

Comment: A profitable deal all around. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Turning first to the second condition. This can obviously only hold if the LHS is 1. This only happens if the exponent is even. Factoring in the floor function, the second condition thus gives us 
$$ x \in \amalg_{n \text{ even}} \lbrack n, n+1) .$$
Now, turning to the first condition. Simpliyfing the original expression and using the binomial theorem, we may rewrite this as
$$ (x-y)^2 \leq 0$$
This inequality can obviously only hold with equality. We conclude from here that $x=y$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Exactly how are you claiming to deduce $x \leq y$ from $(x - y)^2 \leq 0?$

Comment: Edited my answer to get rid of the faulty approach.

Comment: That makes sense now (although - minor point -  you've mixed up the first and second conditions).

Comment: What is $\coprod$?